# Akka : How to get actor causing exception on supervisor

Tags: java, akka

How can i get which child actor had exception on supervisor.
Basically i want to process other things like logging failure to DB, etc..
before stopping the failing actor. But for this i had to know exactly which actor
had the exception.

My supervisorStrategy code block like

```
/* stop task actor on unhandled exception */
private static SupervisorStrategy strategy = new OneForOneStrategy(
        1,
        Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
        new Function<Throwable, SupervisorStrategy.Directive>() {
            @Override
            public SupervisorStrategy.Directive apply(Throwable t) throws Exception {
                return SupervisorStrategy.stop();
            }
        }
);

@Override
public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {
    return strategy;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you watch the child, you will receive [`Terminated`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.3/index.html#akka.actor.Terminated) message with `actor` field and other info. See also [What Lifecycle Monitoring Means](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html). You can also process failure inside child actor itself, by overriding its [`preRestart`/`postRestart`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.3/index.html#akka.actor.Actor) method.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this answer.  Explicitly watching the child should not be required here.

Comment: I'm not requiring it to be explicit anywhere. Explicitly or not - every child is watched.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the following link about [Fault Tolerance](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/java/fault-tolerance.html), you can see that you can, within a supervision strategy, get the failing child actor ref according to this piece of info:

> If the strategy is declared inside the supervising actor (as opposed
>   to a separate class) its decider has access to all internal state of
>   the actor in a thread-safe fashion, including obtaining a reference to
>   the currently failed child (available as the `getSender` of the failure
>   message).

So if you use `getSender` inside of you supervision strategy you should be able to determine which child produced the exception and act accordingly.

Comment: agree with answer, but not sure that things like "logging failure" should be processed there, as intension of strategy is to choose effect on the actor's lifecycle.